# View the value of selected radio button in an input field

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

[image]

As you can see in the above image. I have set of radio buttons, shown as picture. My client wanted to see picture instead of radio buttons. What also he wants is when user click an image (radio button), the value of that button should get displayed in the textarea field below. So user can see the value of selected radio button and **also** he should be able to edit it before he click save. 
So user see what he selected and he can can also type before save.

I am using Jquery for this. So when user click the radio button, I capture the value the text of what user clicked and save in variable. Than I set the value of textarea field to that variable.

All works but the problem is when user select something and type something, and than if he click another picture, the field does not clear.

Question:
How I can copy the clicked value of clicked image and show in field and also allow user to type and if he click another image the field should become clear.

**Here is my code**

**HTML**

```
<div class="text-center">
    <h4>Select reason</h4>
             <form id="timer-reason">
                <div class="row">
                 <div class="col-md-12">
              <?php
                    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($timer_reasons)) {
                ?>
                  <label class="select-reason" value="<?php echo $row['description_tmr']; ?>" id="<?php echo $row['id_tmr']; ?>">
                    <input type="hidden" id="reason-id" value="<?php echo $row['id_tmr']; ?>">
                    <input type="radio" name="ReasonSelect" value="<?php echo $row['description_tmr']; ?>" />
                    <img src="../../css/timer-reasons/<?php echo $row['image_tmr']; ?>" style="width:30%;" class="TimerReason">
                  </label>
                  <?php 
                     }
                    ?>
                     <div class="form-group">

                    <textarea class="form-control" id="reason" value="" rows="2"></textarea>
                 </div>

             </div>
        </div>


</div>
```

**JQUERY**

```
   $('input:radio').click(function() {

   var reasonvalue=$(this).attr("value");
   $("#reason").text(reasonvalue);


  });
```

Answer (score 0):

This is due to how the browser displays textarea's value that is supplied by putting text between the opening / closing tags, setting innerText / textContent

```
<textarea>Value between tags</textarea>
```

And a value supplied by the `value` property.

```
<textarea id="reason"></textarea>
document.getElementById('reason').value = "Value by property";
```

You can set the  innerText / textContent multiple times, but as soon as it gets a set `value` property, which also happens when the user starts typing, changing the innerText / textContent will no longer change **the visible text** shown. The actual property is changed though.

```js
var reasonTextarea = document.getElementById('reason');

var tcBtn = document.getElementById('tcTest');
var tcBtn2 = document.getElementById('tcTest2');
var propBtn = document.getElementById('propTest');

tcBtn.addEventListener('click',function(){
  reason.textContent = "textContent set";
});

tcBtn2.addEventListener('click',function(){
  reason.textContent = "textContent set again";
});

propBtn.addEventListener('click',function(){
  reason.value = "value property set, now try typing something and/or hitting the change by textContent button again.";
});
```

```html
<textarea id="reason" rows=5 cols=40>Test value 1</textarea>

<button id="tcTest">Click to change value by textContent</button>
<button id="tcTest2">Click to change value by textContent again</button>

<button id="propTest">Click to change value by property</button>
```

And this is what is happening with your code, you use jQuery's .text() method which changes the textContent of the textarea. Which will work as long as you never set the `value` property or the user never types in the textarea.

To combat this you should change the value of the textarea by changing the `value` property instead of the textContent property.

```
jQuery('#reason').val('New value');
```

Answer (score -1):

Try Below code. It Should work

```
$('input[type=radio]').click(function() {
  var reasonvalue = $(this).attr("value");
  $("#reason").val(reasonvalue);
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
$(function () {
  $('[name=ReasonSelect]') // bind event on all inputs with name RadioSelect
   .on('change', function() { // on a change execute the function
     var v = $('[name=ReasonSelect]:checked'); // get the selected value
     $("#reason").val( v ); // put the value in #reason.
  });
});
```